# PNG or JPEG With Custom Text Chunk

Tags: c#, png, jpeg, exif

I normally like to ask much more precise questions but in this one I haven't found any good place to get started.

Writing in C#, I am trying to add a large custom text chunk to an image and save this using either JPEG or PNG. I have found plenty of examples on using the Comments or UserComments tag and they work when the text is relatively short. In my case I need to add potentially large chunks of text, let's say up to 256K. I have found references to "custom chunks" but I can't find any good pointers on how to write and read them from C# without having to write a complete custom JPG or PNG encoder.

Comment: JPEG data segments are limited to 64K in size. In order to encode larger blocks of data you will need to split it up into multiple blocks. Check out ICC color profiles in JPEG files for an example of how to do this. Either PNG or JPEG can accomplish what you want and neither is very difficult to squeeze data in that will be ignored.

Comment: Hello Eric, any news about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about JPG, but PNGs have a chunked format and as such it should be easy to add a custom chunk to a file that (well-written) existing decoders will ignore. This chunk can contain whatever data you want to put in it.

You also don't need to write a full PNG decoder, simply look for you custom chunk and read/write it.

Edit: [JPEGs use segments](http://class.ee.iastate.edu/ee528/Reading%20material/JPEG_File_Format.pdf) (see page 2) to separate pieces of files. From my research, I didn't see any way to add a custom segment - but it is possible to use segment ids that are unused (that will be skipped by decoders) like JPG0, JPG13, DHP, EXP or something else. You can even split up the data across multiple blocks to increase the storage space (as pointed out by @BitBank).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick input. Yes, seems that PNG can take a custom chunk of arbitrary length. I found the FreeImage library (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net) with a C# wrapper and a quick test seems to work writing and reading large chunks using XMP as the chunk type.

This solution requires adding 2 DLLs which is not very desirable but works for now.

If anyone knows how to add arbitrary length custom chunks using the standard .NET PngEncoder please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [this library](http://code.google.com/p/pngcs/), it allows to read/write all standard chunks (including the three textual chunks). The last sample [here](http://code.google.com/p/pngcs/wiki/Overview) creates a text chunk.

Comment: Thanks RobIII and leonbloy for the additional information. For now I stuck to the ImageFreeNet library as it does the job though I have to include an additional DLL with my executable. It's a good compromise, not having to work on that aspect more.

BTW, FreeImageNet seems to have a bug when writing & reading text on an XMP chunk. Sometimes there are a few extra characters added to the text. I can't figure out the exact scenario that causes it but it consistently works/fails for a given text. I have a workaround so I am all set for now.

Answer (score 0):

As the most, simple, basic idea (e.g. 'dirty hack'): you wouldn't have to "write a complete custom JPG or PNG encoder". You could save as you normally would, then open the file, stuff in the "custom chunk" and save it.

You would, probably, need to parse some JPG/PNG header information to know at what offset you can put your chunk and you might even need to update some header(s) with new offsets but all-in-all this might be not as much work as writing a complete encoder.

Please note: I do **not** recommend this method, but if all other options are either too much work, too complicated or whatever then this is, at the very least, an option to consider.
Also, I don't know this from the top of my head, but either format *might* actually not even support such 'large' chunks of "non-image data".

If your application is the only application using the images, you might simply consider 'wrapping' the original file in your own 'format' (could be anything from a zip/gz stream containing the image + text as separate files to a single file which could be your own custom fileformat)